# How to re-specialize a template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a template:

```
template<class T>
```

and I expect `T` to be a specialized container, for example, `std::array<int, 5>`.

And, having this `std::array<int, 5>`, I would like to somehow craft a type that would look like this: `std::array<std::pair<bool, int>, 5>`.

Is it possible?

I suppose, if I could somehow extract a pure, unspecialized `std::array` from `std::array<int, 5>`, and the parameters specializing this `std::array` as a parameter pack, I could do it like this:

```
template<typename Container, typename T, typename ...Rest>
using rc = Container<std::pair<bool, T>, Rest...>;

using respecialized_container =
    rc<unspecialized_container, container_parameters>;
```

But, to do this, I need to have this `unspecialized_container` and `container_parameteres`...

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: It's easy to do just for `array`, but harder in general, because your client templates can have both type and non-type parameters, and that's hard to generalize over. Also, you'd need to rebind the allocator parameter for the dynamic containers.

Comment: We're not editing the [tag:c++] tag into your questions because it's fun to do; we're doing it because we'd like _you_ to start properly tagging your questions, please. Take a hint!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay, I will. Outta simple curiosity though, did you remember me among that huge crowd of SO users, or do you have some list of potentially problematic users visible only to high reputation veterans, and I happened to have been placed on that list for notoriously forgetting to add the c++ tag?

Comment: @gaazkam: I had a hunch, so I spent sixty seconds on your profile page.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial approach that works for both `std::array` and the simple standard library containers (the ones that take exactly two parameters):

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template <typename> struct boolpair_rebind;

template <typename C> using boolpair_rebind_t = typename boolpair_rebind<C>::type;

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct boolpair_rebind<std::array<T, N>>
{
    using type = std::array<std::pair<bool, T>, N>:
};

template <typename T, typename Alloc, template <typename, typename> class DynCont>
struct boolpair_rebind<DynCont<T, Alloc>>
{
    using NewT = std::pair<bool, T>;
    using type = DynCont<
                     NewT,
                     typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::rebind_alloc<NewT>>;
};
```

Now given, say, `T = std::array<int, 5>`, you get

```
boolpair_rebind_t<T> = std::array<std::pair<bool, int>, 5>;
```

and given `U = std::list<float>`, you get

```
boolpair_rebind_t<U> = std::list<std::pair<bool, int>>;
```

You can extend this to other container class templates on a case by case basis by adding partial specializations of `boolpair_rebind`.